# Adding comma's and and's between lists

Tags: python, list, code-formatting

How do I add a comma between every list element and an "and" between the last 2 so the output would be:

```
My cats are: Bella
My cats are: Bella and Tigger
My cats are: Bella, Tigger and Chloe
My cats are: Bella, Tigger, Chloe and Shadow
```

Here're the two functions I have, both don't work properly:

```
Example = ['Bella', 'Tigger', 'Chloe', 'Shadow']

def comma_and(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print('My Cats are:',', '.join(list[:i]), 'and', list[-1],)


def commaAnd(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print('My Cats are:',', '.join(list[:i]), list.insert(-1, 'and'))
```

My current output is:

```
>> comma_and(Example)
My Cats are:  and Shadow
My Cats are: Bella and Shadow
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger and Shadow
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger, Chloe and Shadow

>> commaAnd(Example)
My Cats are:  None
My Cats are: Bella None
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger None
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger, Chloe None
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is already almost what you want. You just have to make sure that you don’t always take the last element from the list (`-1`) but the last item from the current iteration:

```
>>> for i in range(len(list)):
        print('My Cats are:',', '.join(list[:i]), 'and', list[i])

My Cats are:  and Bella
My Cats are: Bella and Tigger
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger and Chloe
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger, Chloe and Shadow
```

And then you just need to special-case the first iteration when there is only a single item:

```
>>> for i in range(len(list)):
        if i == 0:
            cats = list[0]
        else:
            cats = ', '.join(list[:i]) + ' and ' + list[i]
        print('My Cats are:', cats)


My Cats are: Bella
My Cats are: Bella and Tigger
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger and Chloe
My Cats are: Bella, Tigger, Chloe and Shadow
```

Comment: Thanks! The code I had first was similar to this, but not as clean as yours. The teacher said it's possible to rewrite this in 3 lines. It seems impossible to me! Your answer already helped me understand what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The condition where there is only one cat in the list needs special handling. What I'll do is, first join the elements of list starting from index 0 till second last element with a comma.

`', '.join(list[:-1])` does this part. The point worth noting here is if the list has only one cat then `list[:-1]` will be an empty list and thus `', '.join(list[:-1])` will be an empty string. So, I just took advantage of this empty string in finding out if the list has only one cat.

```
def comma_and(list):
    cats = ', '.join(list[:-1])
    if cats:
        cats += ' and ' + list[-1]
    else:
        cats = list[0]
    print("My cats are: " + cats)
```

Comment: Thanks! I already had 2 solutions similar like that but I need to have the output in separate lines

Comment: @Denisuu oh! then poke's answer is exactly what you need.

Comment: I also tried your code to understand it but it's not working properly if I only ask for list object 0 ex: comma_and(cats[0]) I get: B, e, l, l, and a. it works when I do comma_and(cats[1]) though.

Comment: @Denisuu it expects a list of cats as input but by passing cats[0] you are passing a single cat.